# jquery class change showing animation insted of instant switch

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I got 2 div's in my application with 2 disserent image dimensions in each, on click I need to switch the classes between them. Everything working fine but .

The switch to class big_div to small_div is working perfectly .. no prob, no image animation

But the switch to small_div to big_div showing some image animation from current size to proposed big size.

How to made the instance width change of class with out animation ? The code looks like

CSS

```
.big_div {
width:600px;
height:400px;
float:left;
border:1px solid #cacaca;
}

.big_div img {
width:150px;
height:100px;
float:left;
margin:10px;
}


.small_div {
width:600px;
height:400px;
float:left;
border:1px solid #cacaca;
}

.small_div img {
width:300px;
height:200px;
float:left;
margin:10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="big" class="big_div"></div>
<div id="small" class="small_div"></div>
<a id="switch">Click</a>
</body>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#switch').click(function(){
        $('#big').switchClass( "big_div", "small_div",1 );
        $('#small').switchClass( "small_div", "big_div",1 );

});

});
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: I think your css classes are wrong in your HTML

Comment: toggleClass is that what u want

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggleClass` instead

```
$('#switch').click(function(){
    $('#big, #small').toggleClass("big_div small_div");
});
```

[reference](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess toggleClass is what you want. But switchClass should work as well.

Maybe it's because of the version of jQuery and jQueryUI you are using. I test both of them with jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.9. They all work perfect fine.

Comment: Two examples can be found: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anthony_yuan/Fb67v/1/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anthony_yuan/Fb67v/3/)